# How can I group by day name in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently using the following to group a count by date...

@texts_by_day = Text.group("DATE(date)").count

I'd like to change it to group by the day of the week. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is dependent on the database you use.  Look up the date methods your database provides and find the one that converts a date into the day of the week.